# Is $\mathbb Z[x^2]$ an ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals, polynomial-rings

Here is the. Question I am wondering about:

Is $\mathbb Z[x^2]$ an ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$?

My question is:

My professor defined $\mathbb Z[x^2]$ as the polynomials in which only even powers of $x^2$ appears, but I do not agree with him as all powers of $x^2$ I think can appear. Am I correct?

Also, I think the answer to the main question I am asking is yes, am I correct?

Comment: If that is what your professor said, he was wrong, but probably meant the polynomials in $x$ where only even powers occur.

Comment: I think he meant even powers of $x$. An ideal in a ring $R$ "absorbs" elements of $R$ by multiplication - does $\mathbb{Z}[x^2]$ do that?

Comment: @AlgTop1854 I think it does, what prevents it?

Comment: Note that $x \cdot x^2 \notin \Bbb Z[x^2]$

Comment: @BenGrossmann beat me to it!  Is it possible you are confusing ideal with subgroup? $\mathbb{Z}[x^2]$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ under addition, but to be an ideal involves the ring structure and is stronger.

Comment: The only ideal which contains $1$ is the entire ring, for any ring.